# How to reach this sum from the following limit?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions

I have come across this in a probability question, and couldn't reach it by myself, and in the solution it's done in one step and I'm unsure as of why it's correct: 
$$\sum^{m-1}_{i=0}\binom{\lfloor{nt}\rfloor}{i}(\frac{\lambda}{n})^i(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{-i}(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{\lfloor{nt}\rfloor}$$
When $n \to \infty$, The answer is: 
$$\sum^{m-1}_{i=0}\frac{(\lambda t)^i}{i!}e^{-\lambda t}$$
I know that formally I need to use the squeeze theorem for $\lfloor{nt}\rfloor$, but working with intuition something seems off for me: 
$(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{\lfloor{n t\rfloor}}\to e^{-\lambda t}$. 
($1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{-i}\to 1$. 
What confuses me is how did they get rid of ($\frac{\lambda}{n})$ which goes to $0$ when $n\to \infty$, I'm trying to open the binomial, but I'm not sure how to deal with the $(nt)!$. 
Any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only missing part is the following (I'm ignoring the floor, it does not affect the asymptotics)
$$
\binom{nt}{i}\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^i = \frac{nt(nt-1)\cdots(nt-i+1)}{i!}\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^i = t\left(t-\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdots \left(t-\frac{i-1}{n}\right) \frac{\lambda^i}{i!}.
$$
Now let $n\to \infty$ and get $\binom{nt}{i}\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^i\to \frac{(\lambda t)^i}{i!}$.

Answer (score 3):

The original expression in the sum is a binomial

$$X\sim Bin\left(\lfloor{nt}\rfloor;\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)$$

using the proper MGF (Moment Generating Function) you get

$$M_{X}(u)=\left[1-\frac{\lambda}{n}+\frac{\lambda}{n}e^u  \right]^{\lfloor{nt}\rfloor}=\left[  1+\frac{\lambda(e^u-1)}{n}\right]^{\lfloor{nt}\rfloor}=\text{when $n\to \infty$}=e^{\lambda t(e^u-1)}$$

and we immediately recognize a MGF of a Poisson, $Po(\lambda t)$ which gives the result of

$$\frac{(\lambda t)^i}{i!}e^{-\lambda t}$$